# Multiple datasource define in di.xml magento2

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, di

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="customerreport_customer_form_data_source" xsi:type="string">Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Grid\CollectionReport</item>
                <item name="customerreport_customer_report_data_source" xsi:type="string">Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Grid\CollectionSubReport</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Grid\CollectionReport">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">subscription_history</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">Tatva_Subscription_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">Tatva_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Grid\CollectionSubReport">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">subscription_history</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">Tatva_Subscription_report_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">Tatva_report_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you achieve this?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Is that is same way like the code in the question or update the code in the answer if it is not.

Comment: @SaravananDS please find my answer and let me know if you have any query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can define number of datasource in di.xml .

Here is example of 3 datasource define in one di.xml:

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="customerreport_customer_form_data_source" xsi:type="string">Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Grid\CollectionReport</item>
            <item name="customerreport_customer_report_data_source" xsi:type="string">Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Grid\CollectionSubReport</item>
            <item name="customerreport_customer_free_report_data_source" xsi:type="string">Tatva\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Grid\CollectionReport">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">subscription_history</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">Tatva_Subscription_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">Tatva_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Tatva\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Grid\Collection">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">customer_entity</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">customer_entity</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">customer_entity</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Tatva\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription\Grid\CollectionSubReport">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">subscription_history</argument>
        <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">Tatva_Subscription_report_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">Tatva_report_grid_collection</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Tatva\Subscription\Model\ResourceModel\Subscription</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```